# Newbie questions for ubuntu server setup?

Tags: networking

I am new to ubuntu. I am testing it using virtual machine. I have installed 2 ubuntu 10.04, and i want to make 1 act as server and the other as a client. My questions:

1. How do I add an additional file system and make sure it mount at the boot time. Lets say I want to make it on /newContent directory? (what are the commands?)
2. How to edit the /etc/exports file, then export /newContent, /newMovies and /backup to my NFS client(use any NFS options).
3. Lastly, how do I test the mounting of the file system on my client side?

If I could test it successfully:

1. I want to mount the file systems on client using auto mounter. How to create a new autofs map (lets call it auto.myDocuments) with a mount point of /myDocuments? And the auto.myDocuments map should mount all directories exported the NFS server i.e. newContent, newMovies and back as descendants of /myDocuments.

Thanks =)

Comment: Please split these up into separate questions, they're easier to answer than one huge question.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at this guide.

http://ubuntuguide.org/wiki/Ubuntu:Lucid

This is what I used when I started ubuntu back in the day with 06.04. It should have information about everything you want to do. If you get stuck and have a more specific question.. feel free to ask it.